# Tkinter (dynamic) Frame doesn't show up

Tags: python, layout, tkinter, frame

I would like to create a GUI program with Tkinter. My idea is a mainWindow with a menuBar and a MainFrame, which shows dynamic content.

I wanted to add the MainFrame by this:

```
MainFrame = Frame(self, bd = '2')
MainFrame.pack(anchor = CENTER)
```

but nothing happens. Are there any ideas? Thanks for your help.

program code:

```
class View(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)
        self.title('Device Configurator')
        self.geometry('500x400')
        self.resizable(0,0)

        self.countFrame = Frame(self, bd = 2, relief = RIDGE)
        self.countFrame.pack(pady = 10, padx = 5)    

        MainFrame = Frame(self, bd = '2')
        MainFrame.pack(anchor = CENTER)

        menubar = Menu(self)
        filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        filemenu.add_command(label='Configure Devices', command= None)
        filemenu.add_command(label='Exit', command=self.quit)
        menubar.add_cascade(label='File', menu=filemenu)

        infomenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff = 0)
        infomenu.add_command(label='About', command = None)
        menubar.add_cascade(label='Info', menu = infomenu)

        self.config(menu = menubar)



class Controller(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.view = View()
        self.view.mainloop()

c = Controller()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, your frame is successfully added but is zero size (and moreover invisible!).

You might either add some content in, or ask the layout manager to give it all the available space `MainFrame.pack(expand=True, fill="both")` .

To make it visible, `borderwith` (alias `bd`) is not sufficient. It must be combined with relief (for instance `relief=SUNKEN`). Another way to "see" your frame is to set a `background`.